# Filter and update functions in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

What are these functions?

Where can I read about how they work?

The CouchDB definitive guide doesn't explain it, weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the CouchDB definitive guide:

> There are other design document
>   functions that are being introduced at
>   the time of this writing, including
>   _update and _filter that we aren’t covering in depth here. **Filter
>   functions are covered in Chapter 20,
>   Change Notifications.** Imagine a web
>   service that POSTs an XML blob at a
>   URL of your choosing when particular
>   events occur. PayPal’s instant payment
>   notification is one of these. With an
>   _update handler, you can POST these directly in CouchDB and it can parse
>   the XML into a JSON document and save
>   it. The same goes for CSV, multi-part
>   form, or any other format.

More info on update from the wiki:

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers