# Can CouchDB natively convert plain text to json format?

Tags: json, couchdb

I'm aware that there are python and powershell methods to convert plain text files, csv's etc.... into json format for upload into NoSQL DBs such as CouchDB.

But according to the CouchDB definitive guide, it makes it seems like there is a native built in way of doing this kind of conversion, without the need for a 3rd party tool.

This older thread appears to hint at this:
[Filter and update functions in CouchDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952419/filter-and-update-functions-in-couchdb)

This part in particular:

> There are other design document functions that are being introduced at the >time of this writing, including _update and _filter that we aren’t covering in >depth here. Filter functions are covered in Chapter 20, Change Notifications. >Imagine a web service that POSTs an XML blob at a URL of your choosing when >particular events occur. PayPal’s instant payment notification is one of >these. With an _update handler, you can POST these directly in CouchDB and it >can parse the XML into a JSON document and save it. The same goes for CSV, >multi-part form, or any other format.

But when I dig deeper I don't find anything concrete.
The supporting wiki link is not clear to me (a beginner with json/NoSQL/curl stuff: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers

Hopefully this is a simple yes/no. And any links to help on this that is better than the above link also appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Their [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/) is quite thorough and gives a much clearer explanation of things apart from old blog posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchDB supports transforming the internal documents/views into many other formats through the use of [show](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#show-functions) and [list](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#list-functions) functions. It's not a "native" transformation, as you define the transformation yourself, it's not magical.

That being said, there is not a similar mechanism for the reverse (ie: converting some arbitrary format into JSON documents) but you're much better off scripting that with a full-featured language/script and using the [bulk docs API](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-bulk-docs) to do your imports in batch.

Comment: Thank you sir. I figured this was the case but wanted to be thorough. I do have a plain text file uploaded as an attachment to my couchdb instance. I was hoping I could use show/list features to get it to output the file in json format but sounds like that is not possible either? I'm happy o dive into the documentation but it will take me a little while to figure out so I'm hoping to get some idea in advance if this can do what I'm hoping for.